# azure web app org.mentalis.security Couldn't acquire crypto service provider context exception

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service

I've deployed an azure web app.
The app contains legacy code using org.mentalis.security.dll for reading mail from an external pop server.
In visual studio local environment all runs fine, while the online app bump with this error:

> System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException occurred Message:
>   A first chance exception of type
>   'System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException' occurred in
>   Org.Mentalis.Security.dll Additional information: Couldn't acquire
>   crypto service provider context.

I suspect this is a permission/authorization problem, but i don't know ho to fix it.
Someone has any clue for help me?
many thanks
nicola

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved:
- abandoned legacy pop read library based on org.mentalis.security.dll
- referenced openpop.net library

now all things look much better